# Determine if document ACTUALLY has focus

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto

Is there a property or function in VSTO that I could use to determine whether a document has the actual keyboard focus? The property or function should return false when the document is *current* but not *focused*, e.g. when showing a modal dialog or alert. Note that `ActiveWindow` or `ActiveDocument` fail to do that, plus `Application.WindowDeactivate` doesn't seem to fire when an alert gets focused.

This is Word 2013 (desktop) + VSTO 4 + C# + .NET Fx 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible only using WinAPI.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

bool WordHasFocus {
    get {
        IntPtr wordHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
        IntPtr focusedWindow = GetForegroundWindow() ;
        return wordHandle == focusedWindow;
    }
}
```

It shows you only that word has focus. If you want to check about given document, you additionally need to ensure that given document is active document.

Comment: Hmm... one thing: will `GetFocus()` return the handle of **alert** if one is currently showing in Word?

Comment: If the alert is a real window then yes,. If it's a taskpane then no.

Comment: An alert is a standard Windows MessageBox. Don't know if that qualifies for a "real" window.

Comment: yes, it is a real window, At least, GetForgroundwindow() will return the handle of it.